# Testing boolean condition with grep on a remote host in a bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, grep

In a shell script I'm writing, I want to check whether a file on a remote host contains the word "open".

From the command line, I can do this successfully using

```
ssh user@remote_host 'grep "open" remote/folder/file'
```

When I was testing this in a local folder, the following worked:

```
    if grep -q "open" local/folder/file; then
        echo ...
```

I'm not sure how to format the conditional using `ssh`, though. Double quotes? Brackets? Just putting the above `ssh` command (which works from the command line) into brackets doesn't work:

```
if [ ssh user@remote_host 'grep -q "open" remote/folder/file' ]; then ...
```

All pointers appreciated.

Comment: I can't answer it better than this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code

Comment: Remove `[` and `]`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it would be so simple.